# Is it possible to overwrite a line of a different length in the file?

Tags: c++

I have a user data file:

```
login1
password1
---------
login2
password2
---------
```

And I want to change the user's password, but I don't understand if this can be achieved without overwriting the entire file?
i wrote :

```
inline void UsersFileHandler::changePasswordByLogin(std::string login){
    std::ifstream readStream;
    std::ofstream writeStream;
    readStream.open(USERS_FILE);
    std::string userData;
    int position = 0;
    while (std::getline(readStream, userData)) {
        if (userData == login) {
            writeStream.open(USERS_FILE, std::ios::app);
            std::string newPassword;
            std::cout << "Enter new password : ";
            std::cin >> newPassword;
            //get password 
            std::getline(readStream, userData);
            //userData.replace(1, 2, "1");
            //readStream.tellg();
            writeStream.seekp(1);
            writeStream.put('1');
            return;
        }
        position += userData.size();

    }
    std::cout <<std::endl<< "User is not found";
    return;

}
```

I tried using `seekp`, but it writes to the end of the file.I tried to make a `replace()` for the line, but it doesn't work either.How can I get a line to be overwritten?

Comment: I am afraid that is hardly possible operating on the file alone. However, if you read the entire file into memory, make the change and then write the entire file back to disk, it is no longer a problem. Another option would, of course, be to write a temporary file which is a line-by-line-copy of the original file, except for the line you actually want to change.

Comment: consider that you usually want to be able to recover the orginal file even if something went wrong during modifying it. Hence one usually reads the whole file into memory, modifies the contents, writes a second file, deletes the old file, renames the new file. If anything goes wrong you still have the original